# Pythonic way to expand list elements as individual actual parameters to a function (like matlab)?

Tags: python, matlab, function, parameter-passing

Let's say at I have a function `f` which has some required and optional formal parameters (and so can be called with a different number of arguments at different points).  Say for a particular call to `f` I have a list, `L`, which has, in order, the arguments I want to pass to `f`.  Is there any way to call `f` using `L` such that the ith element of `L` is used as the `i`th actual parameter passed to `f`?

Or more generally, having a the list L be expanded to the next arguments passed.

In matlab terms `L` would be a cell array so if I had a matlab function `f`

```matlab
function val=f(a1,a2,a3, a4)
    % test to see if a4, opt arg, was passed
    % if not, default it to 0;
    if(~exist('a4','var')) 
       a4=0;
    end
    val = a1+a2+a3+a4;
end
```

and a matlab cell array,`C` (conceptually corresponds to the python list `L` above)

```matlab
C = {1,2,3};
```

I could call `f` like:

```matlab
result=f(C{:}) % so result= 6
```

so `C{i}` is passed as the `i`th argument.

Another call to `f` the input cell array might 4 items and use the same syntax to call `f`

or this

```matlab
result = f(1,C{i,J})
```

so the first arg passed is 1 and the rest are the cell array elements `i` through `j`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a * in front of the list name in the function call (look here for more info http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

So, if your list was L, you would do

```py
result = f(*L)
```

If you only want to use certain elements of L, say from i to j (not including j since slicing is exclusive on the right side), then first slice the list, and then do the same as above:

```py
result = f(*L[i:j])
```

For your last example of inputting an argument and using other list elements as other arguments, it's similar, see below:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def f(a, b, c, d):
    return b
print(f(1, *lst[1: 4]))
#this would print 2
```